# Nginx and PHP: How do you only allow a file download under a certain condition?

Tags: php, authentication, nginx, file-permissions

I am building an e-commerse web application and am working on the delivery of digital content. I have a PHP script which returns true if a customer's payment was successfully processed, and that is the only condition under which I would like someone to be able to download a digital file.

Upon a successful payment, I would like to display a confirmation page with a link to download the file the customer has purchased.

I do not want anyone to be be able to just navigate to the location of the file and download it without first paying for it.

I believe I am just missing a very simple topic and the correct terms for searching for the answer escape me. There seems to be a lot of talk for Apache but I believe a lot of that does not apply to Nginx.

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.I would suggest that you find a development forum (perhaps [quora](http://www.quora.com/Computer-Programming)?) to work out generalities. Then, when/if you have specific coding issues, come back to StackOverflow and we'll be glad to help.

Comment: There are many ways to do it, you don't even need a specific server solution. Upon successful transaction, issue a token specific to that customer. If the token is supplied when requesting the file download, go through the usual process of verifying / invalidating the token and serve the file using PHP. However, your question is really too broad and I doubt you can get a straightfoward correct answer (I do expect that reputation hunters with no knowledge will spam this up though).

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest [Nginx's `X-Accel` feature](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/x-accel/). With this feature, you can force some file to be downloaded after passing your checks in the PHP file.

For example, you have a file `/some/dir/some-file.pdf`. Nginx config may look like this:

```
location /protected {
    internal;   #make resource inaccessible for outer world
    alias   /some/dir;
}
```

And your `download.php` file might look like this:

```
<?php

if (isset($_GET['secret']) && $_GET['secret'] == 'my_pass') {
    header('X-Accel-Redirect: /protected/some-file.pdf');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="some-file.pdf"');
} else {
    echo 'no permissions';
}
```

Then, if you request `/download.php?secret=my_pass`, file willl be download, otherwise not.

Of course, this is simplified example. Real-world example must be more secure. I just wanted to demonstrate one of great features Nginx has.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't something simple your're missing; webservers can perform simple authentication but cannot communicate with 'random' cgi script to verify permissions to files.

So; you should choose between:

1. For each client, write a line to a [auth_basic_user_file](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_auth_basic_module.html#auth_basic_user_file) which your webserver then enforces
2. use php's [readfile](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php) to return the file after checking permissions manually

There isn't a big difference between nginx and apache in this case though.